# kubernetes: using value of runAsUser in an environment variable using valueFrom?

Tags: kubernetes, security-context

I have a kubernetes deployment that starts a pod that includes a `runAsUser` key in its `securityContext`. I was hoping I could stick this value in the environment of an initContainer using [valueFrom](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables), like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testdeployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myservice
          image: myimage
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
      initContainers:
        - name: initialize_things
          image: myimage
          env:
            - name: CONTAINER_UID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser
```

That doesn't seem to work:

> The Deployment "testdeployment" is invalid: spec.template.spec.initContainers[0].env[0].valueFrom.fieldRef.fieldPath: Invalid value: "spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser": error converting fieldPath: field label not supported: spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser

Is there any way to make this work? I'm trying to reduce the number of places I'm hardcoding that UID.

Comment: Where do you explicitly need it?  Can you call a function like `getuid()` from code to retrieve it?

Comment: I can't: I need to use it in a `initContainer` running as `root` in order to set filesystem permissions for the container that has the `runAsUser` security context. I tried to make that explicit in the question; I apologize if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cant make this work because [The downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api) **doesnt support** `spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser` as a field.

Btw, in your case more logically was to put full path , I mean `spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser`, but anyway, it wont help

As per [Capabilities of the Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api) - you are able to use only few fields

```
Information available via fieldRef:
metadata.name 
metadata.namespace
metadata.uid 
metadata.labels['<KEY>']
metadata.annotations['<KEY>'] 

In addition, the following information is available through downwardAPI volume fieldRef:    
metadata.labels
metadata.annotations 

The following information is available through environment variables:    
status.podIP 
spec.serviceAccountName 
spec.nodeName 
status.hostIP
```

You can find very similar issue on github closed: [how to get imageID in container](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/84492)