# How to reference the EXTERNAL-IP from ingress-nginx-controller in a kubernetes deployment specification?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Being a novice kubernetes user, I have successfully deployed an application with [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). But now in my application deployment specification, I have need to reference the EXTERNAL-IP of an ingress-nginx-controller (created via `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.47.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`).

I tried doing the following in my deployment specification,

```
- name: HOSTIP                                               
  valueFrom:                                                         
    fieldRef:                                                        
       fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

but that returned a wholly different IP address than the EXTERNAL-IP address value found in the table when I did `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx`.

Is there a way to reference the ingress-nginx-controller EXTERNAL-IP value using the `valueFrom` syntax or is that not possible? And if not, what might be another way to let the deployed pod get at the EXTERNAL-IP value of the ingress-nginx-controller?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cant do that using `valueFrom` because of [The downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api) limitations. PLease check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64326354/9929015) for more details. Prodided last year with all the needed links.
2. You can store this value in the configmap and regularly update with the script for example. Check [Kubernetes - Pass Public IP of Load Balance as Environment Variable into Pod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474098/9929015) for already prepared script.